# Proper Word for 'Writing' Technical Proposal

Tags: word-choice

I am writing my resume and confuse in 'Writing' technical proposal sentence. What is the proper word of it for technical proposal? Is it writing, creating, developing, or other?

Comment: In my shop, everybody gets involved in "creating" and "developing" a proposal, but ***I*** write it. That's what I do--it says so right on my business cards, "Writer".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Writing" works just fine. There isn't a "more formal" version of "writing" that I can think of. Honestly, I really have no idea why you would be worried about this. If you're putting text on a document, then you're writing, whether it be by pen or on a computer through a keyboard.

"Developing" implies that you made a finished product, so unless you made money off of your technical paper, it wouldn't be applicable -- and even then it would not be idiomatic. "Creating" is applicable, but not very idiomatic either, because it could mean that you did not actually finish the technical document.